# WPF ICommand for Collections

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I have this property in my ViewModel that my ViewModel Command uses to enable/disable/validate the properties of the object:

```
    private ServerModel _server;
    public ServerModel Server
    {
        get { return Server; }
        set
        {
            if (_server != null)
                _server.PropertyChanged -= ServerModel_PropertyChanged;

            _server = value;

            if (_server != null)
                _server.PropertyChanged -= ServerModel_PropertyChanged;

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

private void ServerModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
         RenameServersCmd.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

I want to change the

```
private ServerModel _server;
public ServerModel Server;
```

to

```
private ObservableCollection<ServerModel> _serverCollection;
public ObservableCollection<ServerModel> ServerCollection;
```

And of course, because of that (changing from a single Object to a collection of objects) I loose the access to the "Object.PropertyChanged" Event and I loose the ability to subscribe it to the ServerModel_PropertyChanged() Method and the Command RenameServersCmd.RaiseCanExecuteChanged() cannot be called.

What is the Way to implement the Property code for ObservableCollections in this scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) listen to the collection changed event 2) on add, subscribe to the added ServerModels 3) on remove, unsubscribe

Comment: I`ll try that, thanks